# Increasing loss and decreasing accuracy in BERT model with every epoch

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model

I am trying to fine tune a BERT model for text classification. However I am encountering an issue where the accuracy falls drastically after 1 epoch and loss at the same time increases. I don't believe it is the dataset size that is the limiting factor, as I have tried to increase the dataset significantly without any effect on the performance.

I have tried to adjust learn rate from 5e-5 to 0.1 (in increments) and batch size ranging from 8-32 without[enter image description here] much effect.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0WuQ.png)

Any recommendations for what to look out for?

Comment: Can you share more about the classification task at hand? How many classes do you have? Does your training script "converge", i.e., can you achieve a perfect loss on the training set if you only train with very few (~10) instances?

Comment: The classification task was a binary outcome - so 2 classes. Regarding the loss in the training set, then it seems that the loss increases and remains the same after epoch 3.